# Avoid plotmo truncating predictor labels on plot axes

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting nice plots with the R language `plotmo` library, but he's truncating the main labels.

How can I avoid this?
The real name of the variable is `tempMaxima_Maxima` not `tmpMxm_M`.

```
plotmo(mars1, pt.col = 'steelblue1', do.par = F, smooth.col = 2, trace = -1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotmo version 3.5.7 has a new argument to take care of this issue.  Use `prednames.abbreviate=FALSE` for full (non-abbreviated) names in the graphs.

(Plotmo version 3.5.7 will be released in mid-April 2020.)